# how to do a subtraction on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  code     amnt     pre_amnt     
  123      200      200
  124      234      0
  125      231      231
  126      236      0
  128      122      130
```

I want to do a subtraction only when `pre_amnt` is non zero. My desired dataframe would be

```
  code     amnt     pre_amnt    diff    
  123      200      200         0
  124      234      0           0
  125      231      231         0
  126      236      0           0
  128      122      130         8
```

So, if `pre_amnt` is zero then `diff` should be also 0. How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: You may use np.where() method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['pre_amnt'] > 0
df['diff'] = np.where(m, df['pre_amnt'] - df['amnt'], 0)
```

Another solution with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['diff'] = (df['pre_amnt'] - df['amnt']).where(m, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   code  amnt  pre_amnt  diff
0   123   200       200     0
1   124   234         0     0
2   125   231       231     0
3   126   236         0     0
4   128   122       130     8
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

another approach ?

```
data['diff'] = 0
data.loc[data['pre_amnt'] != 0, 'diff'] = abs(data['pre_amnt'] - data['amnt'])

   code  amnt  pre_amnt  diff
0   123   200       200     0
1   124   234         0     0
2   125   231       231     0
3   126   236         0     0
4   128   122       130     8
```